# Elegant way for general controller (GUI based application)

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, architecture

I was wondering, is there an elegant way to organize the main controller for a gui.
For instance, a controller manages clicks and updates from different widgets in the gui.

This controller calls many subcontrollers for the different part of the app, still in my main I have a horrible:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Manager m;
    return a.exec();
}
```

and the Manager is something like

```
Manager::Manager( QObject *parent )
: QObject(parent)
, serv( new Services::ServiceManager(this) )
, window( new Gui::WindowManager(this) )
, blablaManager
```

There is always a need for a root class which links all the subparts together, if you have ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: What *specifically* are you worried about?

Comment: Well, no argument, it can't even compile.  Look into dependency injection for the next two-to-three letter acronym, perhaps.  Maybe you should wait with MVC until you've gained some OOP experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have a more "elegant" solution with another level of indirection.  However, at some point, the elegance outweighs the performance, scheduling and maintenance costs.

Making a "generic" GUI may not justify the cost for a company that only produces 2 or three different GUIs.